# Cross thread operation: Invoking a number of textboxes

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, textbox

I am not really sure if my title is correct since I dont really know what im doing.

I'm creating a form in Visual studio which communicates with an arduino through serialPort.

In the form I have about 9 textboxes which need to be updated / have text appended to them.

When I do that I get the "Cross thread operaton not valid" exception. After looking at stackoverflow I found a solution which is this: [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on][1]

> [1]:
>   [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775367/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-textbox1-accessed-from-a-thread-othe)

This solution works fine for me but its a bit awkward. since I have 9 textboxes ,I had to create 9 "SetText" methods which is quite clunky.
I was wondering if there is a more general solution which I can use on every textbox I have?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need 9 `SetText` methods? Why can't the method take `Control` as parameter ?

Comment: There are many general purpose solutions in the suggested [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, maybe you could consider a more simply way. A quick solucion could be using Shared Events. 
Maybe you can raise a custom event from your class, and then, you only have to heard it from your Form, in order to receive the text or a more complex parameter, such a a Structure or a Class with more info (name of the control to be updated + text, or whatever you need).