# Change text of Button from another form class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to modify something in **Mission Planner** and I want to change button from another class/form in C# in this function :

```
public void CloseAllConnections()
{
    myButton1.Text = "Disconnecting all";

    ... 
}
```

function that is located in :

```
namespace MissionPlanner
{
    public partial class MainV2 : Form
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

the idea is that everything works perfectly when i am focused on that menu, but sometimes i get a error

i even made a function like this

```
public MyButton GetMyButton1 { get { return myButton1; } }
```

and also created new instance

```
var myObject = new MainV2(true);
myObject.myButton1.Text = "Disconnecting all";
```

nothing works ...

i don't even know where is the function called from, because is clear that is not called from `MainV2` class ...

`An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MissionPlanner.exe but was not handled in user code`

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Can we receive some clarification on why this secondary form will be modifying a button value on another form?

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab an instance of the form where the button resides.
Do this by saving a static reference to the form in it's constructor:

```
namespace MissionPlanner
{
    public partial class MainV2 : Form
    {
        public static MainV2 CurrentForm;
        public MainV2()
        {
            CurrentForm = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Then somewhere else in your code:

```
public void CloseAllConnections()
{
    MainV2.CurrentForm.myButton1.Text = "Disconnecting all";

    ... 
}
```

Comment: and in my case what will be `CurrentForm` ? the other form ?

Comment: and also i get this `Error 10 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'myButton1' and no extension method 'myButton1' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\wzi5\ARDUINO\MissionPlanner-master\MissionPlanner-master\MainV2.cs 3014 32 MissionPlanner
` when i am calling `MainV2.CurrentForm.myButton1.Text = "Disconnecting all";` from `public void CloseAllConnections()` function ... what now ?

Comment: CurrentForm will be the current instance of the MainV2 form if it is open. If the MainV2 form is not open then it will be null.

Comment: Sorry, the definition should be:
public static MainV2 CurrentForm;

Edited answer to correct

Comment: i made the modification, i get same error `An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'myButton1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.` what to do?? i don't know ...

Comment: I didn't realise that the CloseAllConnections method is being executed from another thread. This post will solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775367/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-textbox1-accessed-from-a-thread-othe

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your click event form object is called (name) myButton1, and that you are calling the following to change it:  myobject.myButton1.Text = "Disconnecting all".  Try using  myButton1.Text = "Disconnecting all" instead.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could try is to pass the button from the form to the class that will be modifying the button.

```
public class Example
{
    public Button MyButton1 { get; set; }

    public Example(Button myButton1)
    {
        MyButton1 = myButton1;
    }

    public void CloseAllConnections()
    {
        MyButton1.Text = "Disconnecting all";
    }
}
```

This should successfully set the button's text on MainV2.

Comment: thanks for the response, but i get this error even from the beginning `An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MissionPlanner.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` .... what to do?

Comment: Quick question.  Where are you creating the new instance of the class that contains the `CloseAllConnections` method?

Comment: here is the explination : http://pastebin.com/Es0f8Y6z what do you think about this?

Comment: User2747636, I'm not sure if it's just the way it's been pasted into pastebin, but it looks like your `public void CloseAllConnections()` method is within the MainV2 class itself.  Is MainV2 the form which has your button?  If so, then you should just be able to change the text with `myButton1.Text = "Disconnecting all"` without anything I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any sort of multi-threading in your app? if so:
Make sure you either only change the button from the same thread it was created by, 
or simply use the ControlInstance.Invoke() method to delegate the change.