# Refresh the user interface while a separated STA thread is adding many controls

Tags: c#, user-interface, thread-safety, bing-maps

I would like to add pushpins on my map by means of a thread. The thread is STA and I use a dispatcher.

The issue is my map is not refreshed with the pushpins. No pushpin appears on the map.

I've a class named "SerialInterf" which reads a serial port. Each reading invokes the event 'DataReceivedHandler':

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(Object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort port = (SerialPort)sender;
        string data = port.ReadExisting();

        LatLong message = GetData(data);

        SerialInterfEventArgs arg = new SerialInterfEventArgs(message);
        this.MessageReceived(this, arg);
    }
```

The event "DataReceivedHandler" invokes another event of the same class called "MessageReceived". The class SerialInterf is instancied by my MainWindow class. In this last one, the event "MessageReceived" is defined:

```
transm.MessageReceived += new Trans.SerialInterfEventHandler(WriteTrace);
```

The method WriteTrace launches the thread (STA):

```
private void WriteTrace(object sender, TransmissionEventArgs e)
        {
            // On crée un thread car on ne peut pas modifier l'utilisateur interface avec un thread MTA (par défaut).
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => test(e.Message));
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
        }
```

This thread launches the method "test" which must create my pushpins on my map:

```
private void test(LatLong message)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
            {
                Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();
                pin.Location = new Location(message.Latitude, message.Longitude);

                map.Children.Add(pin);
            }));
        }
```

Comment: Work from existing sample code.  Where is your MapLayer?

Comment: I've edited my post. My map is in the MainWindow class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
```

has been modified by

```
this.map.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
```

That's ok now !

See: [Cross-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775367/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-textbox1-accessed-from-a-thread-othe)

I don't think that I need STA thread.