# Cross-Threading issues

Tags: vb.net

This is the first time I have used backgroundworkers and am running into issues with 'Cross Threading'. I have never done anything with this so I am extremely confused.

**Example on issue**

```
 Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    PullIPButton.Enabled = False
        PingAll()

End Sub
```

**Button Sub**

```
Private Sub PullIPButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PullIPButton.Click
    If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        PullIPs() 'From here, it starts the background worker
    End If

End Sub
```

**Error**

The below error comes up when clicking a button, that enables the backgroundworker.

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'PullIPButton' accessed from
>   a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: Answer for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775367/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-textbox1-accessed-from-a-thread-othe

Comment: @HungPV thats C# and I know nothing about how to read that :(

Comment: @sstan got my answer from there. Submit answer for credit

Comment: @dwb: Thanks, but it would be best if you give credit to the "duplicate" post by upvoting the question and any answer you found useful. Glad you found what you needed.