# Threading with listbox in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, listbox

i am developing a code in which a have to read the data form list box and upload an external file, press a button named Start and with this listbox i am getting an error as shown below.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control
>   'listBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created
>   on.

my code is as follows

```
private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Thread ss = new Thread(Automode);  
 ss.Start(); 
} 

 private void Automode()
    {
        ....
       for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);

            string pattern = "[gxyzbcmij][-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*";
            string text = listBox1.Text;
            Regex gcode = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            MatchCollection code = gcode.Matches(text);
        }
        .....   
     }
```

here at listbox.SetSelected command it is giving an exception as shown above. please suggest the alternate ways to write it.

Comment: As always, separate the UI code from the business code... Redesign it so that the thread code doesn't  access the ListBox or any other control.

Answer (score 1):

```
delegate void SetSelectedCall(int index, bool option);

private void SetSelectedElement(int index, bool option)
{
  if (this.listBox1.InvokeRequired)
  { 
    SetSelectedCall d = new SetSelectedCall(SetSelectedElement);
    this.Invoke(d, new object[] { int index, bool option});
  }
  else
  {
    this.listBox1.SetSelected(index,option);
  }
}
```

Taken from [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775367/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-textbox1-accessed-from-a-thread-othe) and tailored for this question.

Comment: This does solve the immediate problem but it does not address the deeper design issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the `listBox1` from a background thread.

If possible, run the code from the function `Automode()` directly in the Start_Click method. If you must have the code ran in a background thread, I would perhaps suggest something more like a Task, that way you can still perform the action based on passing arguments and awaiting a response. Then you can still `listBox1` items as selected.