# Having trouble with using async and await to change UI in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

First, I sorry for my bad Engish.I have just learned C# recently and I still don't know much. I am wiring a C# WinForm app and having trouble when I use 'async' and 'await' to change UI. The program is built successfully. When I debuged, I got this message at 'ActiveForm.Size = scrres.Size;'

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control ''
>   accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

I want to change the form size as same as the screen resolution. Thanks for reading.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RandomNoTHPTChuyenBT
{
    public partial class ldsc : Form
    {
        public ldsc()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Rectangle scrres = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        public Rectangle scrresr
        {
            get
            {
                return scrres;
            }
        }
        private async void ldsc_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if (scrres == new Rectangle(0, 0, 1366, 768))
                {
                    ActiveForm.Size = scrres.Size;
                    pictureBox2.Size = scrres.Size;
                }
                if (scrres == new Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 768))
                {
                    ActiveForm.Size = scrres.Size;
                    pictureBox2.Size = scrres.Size;
                }
            });
            if (scrres == new Rectangle(0, 0, 1366, 768))
            {
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(608, 310);
            }
            if (scrres == new Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 768))
            {
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(437, 309);
            }
       }
```

Comment: You can't alter the UI thread from a Task (another thread)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775367/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-textbox1-accessed-from-a-thread-othe)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how I can change my form size without using another thread?

Comment: By not using another thread?! Why do you think you need a thread to change the form size?

Comment: Well, I searched in Google and someone said that. So how I can change the form size? Please help.

Comment: a simple google search results in plenty of answers, not least of which this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229606(v=vs.110).aspx). BTW, Please read the [help]. comments shouldn't become extended discussions. Your question above is a duplicate, if you have another (different question) you should ask that separately, but **only after checking for duplicates first**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've wrapped your UI code in `Task.Run`.  Don't do that.  The whole point of `Task.Run` is to offload the work to another thread.  You don't want to do that, you want to run it in the UI thread.

Once you've done that you have nothing left to `await`, so you can remove the `async` modifier from the method, as it is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So I have to use 'delegate' instead?

Comment: @GiaBảoTrương I see no reason for you to use a delegate.  All you need to do is remove a bunch of code that you shouldn't have added in the first place.

Comment: When I remove async and await, I received another error.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: @GiaBảoTrương Do not wrap the code in your `ldsc_Load` method in a `Task.Run(...)` but just run everything syncronously on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for reply. If I don't but it in ldsc_load, where I can put it? Because I want that the form size is fixed with the sceen size so it must be done before the form is loaded. Please help.