# How to multithread using serial connection vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, serial-port

I have a serial connection to a remote machine and i'm developing a windows form using vb.net in order to gather some infos.

So as u can see in the code below i'm waiting until i receive the full string ( length 4, # as separator ) to change some textboxes text.

```
Dim ReceivedTextSeries As String = vbNullString

Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)

    If TextBoxConsola.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim x As New SetTextCallBlack(AddressOf ReceivedText)
        Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        ReceivedTextSeries &= [text]
        JustTesting()
    Else
        TextBoxConsolaReceived.Text &= [text]
        ReceivedTextSeries &= [text]
        JustTesting()
    End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub JustTesting()
    Dim Series() As String = ReceivedTextSeries.Split("#")
    If Series.Length = 4 Then
        TextBox1.Text = Series(0)
        TextBox2.Text = Series(2)
    End If
End Sub
```

But i'm getting an error saying that multithreading isn't allowed..
`The operation between threads is not valid: Control 'TextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread where it was created.`

How can i manage this now? I've tried to add event handlers to avoid this but without success..

Comment: Check if Textbox1 requires invoking an invoke it?

Comment: @Malcor what do you mean with "requires invoking" ?

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775367/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-textbox1-accessed-from-a-thread-othe

Comment: well you are already doing it with `TextBoxConsola`. Do it with `TextBox1` and `TextBox2` as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Comment: @the_lotus the fact that it is vb.net is enough to not being a duplicate.. thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you could create a quick sub that invokes your textboxes. You're already doing that in your previous method. This makes it reusable.

```
Private Sub UpdateTextBox(Text As String, TextBox As TextBox)
    If TextBox.InvokeRequired Then
        TextBox.Invoke(DirectCast(Sub() UpdateTextBox(Text, TextBox), Action))
        Exit Sub
    End If
    TextBox.Text = Text
End Sub
```

Then all your calls to write to a textbox can be called with

```
UpdateTextBox("My Text", TextBox1)
```

So with your code you could do

```
Sub JustTesting()
    Dim Series() As String = ReceivedTextSeries.Split("#")
    If Series.Length = 4 Then
        UpdateTextBox(Series(0), TextBox1)
        UpdateTextBox(Series(2), TextBox2)

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I like the part of being reusable !!