# Progress Bar not progressing according to max size

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I'm trying to write a simple program (c#) that read a set of zip files to search for some specific files.

i implemented this using winform and a background worker but i'm having some trouble to understand how to configure the progress bar to progress dynamically according to the number of files i'm parsing.

for example in Directory A i have 400 zip file so i want the "size" of the progress bar to be 400 units so each file a open will increment the progress bar by 1. In directory B i only have 4 zip file so i need 4 block in the progress bar

i tried to do the following code just to test the progress bar
i set the Maximum to 20 (to represent 20 zip files) and in a loop incremnt by 1 the progress bar

```
        private void button_SearchZip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!backgroundWorker_SearchZip.IsBusy)
        {
            SearchZipArgs args = new SearchZipArgs
            {
                sourceDirectory = this.textBox_SrcDir.Text
            };

            backgroundWorker_SearchZip.RunWorkerAsync(args);
            this.button_SearchZip.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Search already in process. please try again later");
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_SearchZip_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

            this.progressBar_SearchZip.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
            //this.progressBar_SearchZip.Step = 1;
            this.progressBar_SearchZip.Minimum = 0;
            this.progressBar_SearchZip.Maximum = 20;
            for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                backgroundWorker_SearchZip.ReportProgress(i);
                Thread.Sleep(300);
            } 
    }

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.backgroundWorker_SearchZip.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        this.backgroundWorker_SearchZip.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker_SearchZip_DoWork);
        this.backgroundWorker_SearchZip.ProgressChanged += new System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker_SearchZip_ProgressChanged);
        this.backgroundWorker_SearchZip.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker_SearchZip_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_SearchZip_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar_SearchZip.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

but this is what i get in the progress bar:

[image: Progress bar screenshot when work is done]

for some reason if uncomment the:

```
this.progressBar_SearchZip.Step = 1;
```

the progress bar is not working at all

any help would be nice :)

Edit:
Found the problem! i was trying to change the progress bar from the background thread and i got an error "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'progressBar Search Zip' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on"
after fixing this error (with the help of this thread: [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775367/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-textbox1-accessed-from-a-thread-othe)) the problem is solved

Comment: Where is backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged event?

Comment: @A3006 forgot to add it. I've edited the question

Answer (score 1):

The `Step` property is used to when calling the [PerformStep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.performstep(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

To set the current position of the progress bar you can use the `Increment` function like this:

```
progressBar.Increment(1);
```

or set its value like this:

```
progressBar.Value = yourValue;
```

Comment: @S. Dav - For my knowledge - Do we need to write these lines in ProgressChanged? I think this gets called from ReportProgress?

Comment: You might be right, but we don't see the ReportProgress function in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
backgroundWorker_SearchZip.ProgressChanged += this.OnProgressChanged;
```

into your initialization function (e.g. `Form_Load`)

and then add

```
private void OnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
  this.progressBar_SearchZip.Increment(1);
}
```

Comment: is it really a good idea to subscribe the `ProgressChanged` event in the Button Click event as per your suggestion? This should preferably be done on `Form_Load` or any other initializing method

Comment: Good point, I misread the question and thought I saw it being initialized in the click event. I'll make an edit

Comment: @S.Dav forgot to add the ProgressChanged code . I've edited the question

Comment: @BobVale this.backgroundWorker_SearchZip.Increment(1) does not complie. did u mean: this.progressBar_SearchZip.Increment(1) ?

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me:

```
this.progress_bar.Properties.Minimum = 0; 
this.progress_bar.Properties.Maximum = datatable.Rows.Count;

foreach (DataRow row in datatable.Rows)     {

   // operation that you need to do     

   this.progress_bar.Increment(1);
   this.progress_bar.Update();
}
```

Good luck

Comment: so if u get 10 rows or 1000 rows - in both cases the progress bar is filled till the end?

Comment: yes, with each iteration in the foreach you increase the value of progress bar by 1 and you update the state of progress bar ....

That sample code is operational in a project that imports rows from a datatable and performs a series of checks with them.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem!

i was trying to change the progress bar from the background thread and i got an error "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'progressBar Search Zip' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on"

after fixing this error (with the help of this thread: [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775367/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-textbox1-accessed-from-a-thread-othe)) the problem is solved