# How is Progress<T> different from Action<T>?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, progress

I've been using `Progress<T>` and wondered if it can be replaced by `Action<T>`.

In the code below, using each of them for reporting progress, i.e. `ReportWithProgress()` or `ReportWithAction()`, didn't make any noticeable difference to me. How `progressBar1` increased, how the strings were written on the output window, they seemed the same.

```
// WinForm application with progressBar1

private void HeavyIO()
{
    Thread.Sleep(20); // assume heavy IO
}

private async Task ReportWithProgress()
{
    IProgress<int> p = new Progress<int>(i => progressBar1.Value = i);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => HeavyIO()); 
        Console.WriteLine("Progress : " + i);
        p.Report(i);
    }
}

private async Task ReportWithAction()
{
    var a = new Action<int>(i => progressBar1.Value = i);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => HeavyIO());
        Console.WriteLine("Action : " + i);
        a(i);
    }
}
```

But `Progress<T>` can't be a reinvention of the wheel. There should be a reason why it was implemented. Googling "c# Progress vs Action" didn't give me much help. How is Progress different from Action?

Comment: I'd suggest you to change `HeavyIO` to `async Task HeavyIO() { await Task.Delay(20); }` so that at least you are invoking a Task

Comment: `Progress<T>` calls the action in the context in which it was constructed which allows you to interact with the UI without annoying invocation code.

Comment: What information did you find in the documentation of `Progress` and how did that fail to answer your question?

Comment: Calling `progressBar1.Value = i` from a different thread results in the dreaded ["cross-thread operation not valid"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10775367/69809) exception.

Comment: Note that [`Progress<T>` is a *class*](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/progress.cs,d23df0450d3fd0d6), while [`Action<T>` is merely a delegate](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/action.cs,486d58da4553e12d).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Calling `progressBar1.Value = i` from a different thread results in the dreaded ["cross-thread operation not valid"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10775367/69809) exception. The `Progress` class, on the other hand, dispatches the event to the [synchronization context](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/progress.cs,79) captured in the moment of construction:

```
// simplified code, check reference source for actual code

void IProgress<T>.Report(T value)
{
    // post the processing to the captured sync context
    m_synchronizationContext.Post(InvokeHandlers, value);
}

private void InvokeHandlers(object state)
{
    // invoke the handler passed through the constructor
    m_handler?.Invoke((T)state);

    // invoke the ProgressChanged event handler
    ProgressChanged?.Invoke(this, (T)state);
}
```

This ensures that all updates to progress bars, labels and other UI elements are done on a (one and only) GUI thread.

So, it only makes sense to instantiate the `Progress` class **outside** of the background thread, inside a method which is called on a UI thread:

```
void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // since this is a UI event, instantiating the Progress class
    // here will capture the UI thread context
    var progress = new Progress<int>(i => progressBar1.Value = i);

    // pass this instance to the background task
    Task.Run(() => ReportWithProgress(progress));
}

async Task ReportWithProgress(IProgress<int> p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => HeavyIO());
        Console.WriteLine("Progress : " + i);
        p.Report(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ChrFin: Well, the "one and only" thread to which your Form's controls are bound to.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that with a `Progress<T>` you have an event where multiple listeners can listen for progress and `Progress<T>` does capture the `SynchonizationContext` when the instance is constructed and thus does not need to be invoked to the GUI-thread if created in the GUI-thread.
You can also add multiple listeners to an `Action<T>` (thanks to @Servy for pointing that out), but each of them are then executed in the thread which invokes the action.

Think of the following extended example, where the `Progress<T>` will work, but the `Action<T>` will [throw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10775367/69809):

```
private async Task ReportWithProgress()
{
    var p = new Progress<int>(i => progressBar1.Value = i);
    p.ProgressChanged += (s, e) => progressBar2.Value = e;

    Task.Run(() => 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                await Task.Run(() => HeavyIO()); 
                Console.WriteLine("Progress : " + i);
                ((IProgress<int>)p).Report(i);
            }
        });
}

private async Task ReportWithAction()
{
    var a = new Action<int>(i => progressBar1.Value = i);
    a += i => progressBar2.Value = i;

    Task.Run(() => 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                await Task.Run(() => HeavyIO());
                Console.WriteLine("Action : " + i);
                a(i);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: `Action<T>` is a multicast delegate.  Any number of methods can be called when you invoke it.