# Using progress bar in WPF C# MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, progress-bar

My goal is to update the progress bar while another set of script (calculations) is running.

I have followed the sample files from [here](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/) and tried to bind it to my MVVM script but the progress bar would not update.

[image]

**Here is the Progressbar script**

In the script below, I have included `progressBarCounter` and `noOfData`as a value in another script that is calculated in a method.

Proof that data is updated

[image]

```
public partial class ProgressBarTaskOnWorkerThread : Window
{
    public ProgressBarTaskOnWorkerThread()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        EtabsDataFormatting.ViewModel.SpliceViewModel data = new EtabsDataFormatting.ViewModel.SpliceViewModel();

        for (int i = data.progressBarCounter; i < data.noOfData;)
        {
            (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
        }
    }

    void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        int perc = Convert.ToInt32(pbStatus.Value);
        UpdateProgress(perc);
    }

    public void UpdateProgress(int percentage)
    {
        pbStatus.Value = percentage;
        if (percentage == 100)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is part of my XAML code for the button to start calculations and run the progressbar**

The command Binding = RunCalcBtn is bound to the calculation scripts, therefore, I have created a click to run the progress bar instead.

```
<Button x:Name = "ApplyButton" Margin="0 1 0 1" Content ="Start Calculation" Command="{Binding RunCalcBtn, Mode=TwoWay}" Click ="PrgBar_Click"/>
```

**Progressbar XAML.cs button click**

This part displays the progress bar, but it does not update.

```
private void PrgBar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ProgressBar.ProgressBarTaskOnWorkerThread progressWindow = new ProgressBar.ProgressBarTaskOnWorkerThread();
    progressWindow.Show();
}
```

Thank you so much for helping me in advance!

Comment: Did you take a look at how you progress bar is bound to the data? How does it know the data is updated?

Comment: Hi Stefan thanks for your help, I've looked at the data update and the data is being updated, I've modified the post to include a picture of it.

Comment: Try "Progress<T>", this is the best way to update progress bar in async way and needn't to associated with the view-model

Comment: @Filthor Thank you for the reply but I have no idea how to use Progress<T> even after searching through
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625152/how-is-progresst-different-from-actiont-c
and
https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html
. Do you have an example where I can use as a reference?

Comment: I don't think background worker is really helping you so much here. Personally I would run a task on a background thread to do lengthy stuff. My preference is to use a spinner or throbber wait indicator which does not show percentage complete. Few processes have equal pieces of processing so even if one process in an app does then most or all the rest probably don't.  Have you debugged your code? You could have data problems like eg if noOfData is 0 or 1 or some such.

Comment: @Nate https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/

Answer (score 2):

As Flithor has said, the best way to achieve this is with `Progress<T>`.

I give a short illustration of how to use this.

Firstly you need to create a `Property` in your View Model so that you can bind the ProgressBar's Value to something.  Your ViewModel will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that the Property `set` can invoke `RaisePropertyChangedEvent`.

Next create a Progress inside the method called by the Button click and pass it to your worker method.  Use an ICommand for this, so that it can be bound to your Button (you don't need the Click event).   Something like this:

```
var progress = new Progress<int>(percent =>
    {
        ProgressProperty = percent;
    });

await Task.Run(() => myWorker(progress));
```

Finally within your worker method you periodically update the value like this:

```
private void myWorker(IProgress<int> progress)
{
    progress.Report(1);
    // ...
    progress.Report(100);
}
```

By way of explanation: I used an integer, but you can also use a double if you want really fine calculations!  The constructor of the Progress object takes the ProgressProperty (the name I gave to the property that gets bound to the ProgressBar) as a parameter.  This means that when the worker calls Report(), the ProgressProperty is automatically updated with the new value, and hence can be reflected in the UI.  Finally your worker method is invoked with await so that the UI is able to update on every incremented value.

For a very full explanation on Progress, see Stephen Cleary's [blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

In **MVVM WPF**, you should do this to take full advantage of it:

**View:**

```
<Grid>
   <ProgressBar Name="myProgressBar"
                Minimum="0" 
                Value="{Binding ProgressBarValue,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                Maximum="100"
                Foreground="{Binding ColorState,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                Background="#424242"
                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                BorderThickness="0"/>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myProgressBar, Path=Value,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}" 
              FontWeight="DemiBold"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace YourNameSpace.Models
{
    public class Device : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Device()
        {
            this.ProgressBarValue = 50; // Your ProgressBar Foreground will be "GREEN" automatically
                                        // This is the 
        }
        
        private double progressBarValue;
        public double ProgressBarValue
        {
            get { return progressBarValue; }
            set 
            { 
                progressBarValue = value; 
                if(progressBarValue < 50)
                    this.ColorState = "Red";
                else if (progressBarValue >= 50)
                    this.ColorState = "Green";
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ProgressBarValue"); 
            }
        }
        private string colorState = "Transparent";
        public string ColorState
        {
            get { return colorState; }
            set { colorState = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ColorState"); }
        }
        
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string Obj)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Obj));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can **REMOVE** this from your code:

```
    void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        int perc = Convert.ToInt32(pbStatus.Value);
        UpdateProgress(perc);
    }

    public void UpdateProgress(int percentage)
    {
        pbStatus.Value = percentage;
        if (percentage == 100)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
```

And **ONLY** use this:

```
for (int i = data.progressBarCounter; i < 100; i++)
{
    ProgressBarValue = i;
}
```

Your

> ProgressBar Value
>
> Progress Foreground Color

will be updated **automatically**.