# Async progress bar in WPF using binding

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, data-binding, progress-bar

I have a problem with visualizing the MVVM WPF progress bar. My methods for the main script runs but the progress bar isn't updating at all. I could use tips on getting in the right direction. In my previous codes, I was given tips to use `Progress<T>` ([by @Jonathan Willcock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451417/using-progress-bar-in-wpf-c-sharp-mvvm)) but I couldn't implement it successfully.

*(Please note that this post is not a repeated question because last time, I used button click but I want it to purely be run on data binding)*

**Question**

How do I asynchronously bind the progress bar to the method which is called in my view models? I am using Delegate command to call my methods and I do not want to use the button click event.

**What I have in the view - XAML**

I have two main functions here, the progress bar and the button. The button starts the method calling successfully but the progress bar doesn't load.

```xml
    <ProgressBar Name="pbStatus"
                         Minimum="0"
                         Value="{Binding PrgBarVal, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         Maximum="100"
                         Height="20"/>
    <Button x:Name = "ApplyButton" Margin="0 1 0 1" Content ="Run software" Command="{Binding RunCalcBtn, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**What I have in the XAML.cs**

What I know from the background worker method is that it tries to run it async. I have an issue here, I added a breakpoint here to check if the code runs through the 'Window_ContentRendered' method but it doesn't.

```cs
    public partial class UserInterface: UserControl
    {
        public UserInterface()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork; //Do I need a worker.ProgressChanged here?
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        thenamespace.ViewModel.SelectedViewModel get = new thenamespace.ViewModel.SelectedViewModel ();
        void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

            for (int i = Convert.ToInt32(get.PrgBarVal); i < 100; i++)
            {
                (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

**What I have in the View Model**

In the view model, I am using delegate command to call my data binding methods.

The `public SelectedViewModel()` is where the `Run()` method is called. In the `Run()` method, the functions in there runs correctly and updates the value of `PrgBarVal` correctly. However, this doesn't update the progress bar at all.

```cs
    public class SelectedViewModel : ModelView, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ModelView modelView { get; set; }

        private DelegateCommand _runCalcBtn;
        public DelegateCommand RunCalcBtn
        {
            get { return _runCalcBtn; }
            set
            {
                _runCalcBtn = value;
                SetPropertyChanged("RunCalcBtn"); //Same as RaisedPropertyChanged
            }
        }
        public SelectedViewModel()
        {
            modelView = new ModelView();
            RunCalcBtn = new DelegateCommand(Run);
        }

        private int _prgBarVal;
        public int PrgBarVal
        {
            get { return _prgBarVal; }
            set
            {
                _prgBarVal = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PrgBarVal"); //Same as RaisedPropertyChanged
            }
        }

        //Main Function
        private async void Run()
        {

            MethodToWork(); //Function that calls other methods to run 
        }
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ViewModel (used [NuGet ReactiveUI.WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReactiveUI.WPF/))

```cs
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private int _workProgress;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>( e => WorkProgress = e );
        StartWork = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask( () => ExecuteStartWorkAsync( progress ) );

    }

    private async Task ExecuteStartWorkAsync( IProgress<int> progress )
    {
        progress.Report( 0 );
        for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
        {
            await Task.Delay( 10 ).ConfigureAwait( false );
            progress.Report( (int)Math.Floor( i / 1000.0 * 100.0 ) );
        }
    }


    public int WorkProgress { get => _workProgress; private set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged( ref _workProgress, value ); }
    public ICommand StartWork { get; }
}
```

and the View

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="Start work" Command="{Binding StartWork}" Width="80"/>
            <ProgressBar Value="{Binding WorkProgress,Mode=OneWay}" Width="120"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```