# VB.NET Checked List Box

Tags: vb.net

I am making a To Do program. I have a checked list box there. I want to make every checked item deleted automatically. Here's the code that I am using to check if checked:

```
For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1




            If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i) Then


            Else

            End If
        Next
```

How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Why are you getting a cross thread exception? Show more code - is this code in eg a backgroundworker dowork event?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes it's a background worker dowork event

Comment: What else is going on in the background worker that requires a separate thread?

Answer (score 1):

To remove Items from your ListBox, you can save items to be removed in your loop and then to delete it for example :

```
Dim itemsToRemove As New List(Of Object)

For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i) Then
        itemsToRemove.Add(CheckedListBox1.Items(i))
    End If
Next

For Each item As Object in itemsToRemove
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Remove(item)
Next
```

Comment: it says System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'CheckedListBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

Comment: @gambi just enumerate the checkboxlist backwards and remove by index

Comment: @TIPD, this might solve your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775367/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-textbox1-accessed-from-a-thread-othe

Comment: @CaiusJard, yes you are right, it works too.

Answer (score 0):

If you loop backwards then removing an item doesn't affect the part of the list you have yet to check

```
For i = CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1 to 0 Step -1
    If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i) Then
        CheckedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next
```

This won't prevent the cross thread exception you're getting; for that we really need to know why you're accessing this Control from a thread other than the thread that created it

Comment: RemoveAt is not a member of 'CheckedListBox'

Comment: CheckedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)